# Active Directory monitor attribute accesses

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to set up monitoring of all read accesses over an attribute.
Searching online I see that event 4662 could be used for that purpose.

The problem is that when I look up for guid of the attribute I am looking for in the 4662 events, I see a tone of logs. All of them, other than the target attribute, they have 4-5 other attributes under the property list, which may be the reason of the noise(?)

Is there a more appropriate way to my task?

The event is similar with the below (let's say I am interested for accesses on property {6617e4ac-a2f1-43ab-b60c-11fbd1facf05}):

> Operation:
>
> Operation Type:
>
> Object Access
>
> Accesses:  Control Access
>
> Access Mask:  0x100
>
> Properties:  ---
>
> {91e647de-d96f-4b70-9557-d63ff4f3ccd8}
>
> {6617e4ac-a2f1-43ab-b60c-11fbd1facf05}
>
> {b3f93023-9239-4f7c-b99c-6745d87adbc2}
>
> {b8dfa744-31dc-4ef1-ac7c-84baf7ef9da7}
>
> {b7ff5a38-0818-42b0-8110-d3d154c97f24}
>
> {771727b1-31b8-4cdf-ae62-4fe39fadf89e}
>
> {612cb747-c0e8-4f92-9221-fdd5f15b550d}
>
> {bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}

Thanks